# How to set "type" or "onclick" attribute in C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to inject a button element into a web page to trigger a function in the hosting application (by using the ObjectForScripting property of the WebBrowser control). However, I cannot seem to set the type or onclick attributes to make this work.
Something like

```
button.SetAttribute("className", "btn btn-warning");
```

works, but

```
button.SetAttribute("type", "button");
```

or

```
button.SetAttribute("onClick", "window.external.Scan(); return false;");
```

does not. The OuterHtml property only displays the button element with its class attribute set and the button in its current state does not perform any action other than submitting the form, which, as you can see from the attributes I'm attempting to set, is not what I intended.